# Called for vs necessary

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I need the native perspective regarding the usage of 'called for' vs 'necessary' in the following example:

```
A) I can understand why you did it, and even forgive it, assuming forgiveness is called for. 
B) I can understand why you did it, and even forgive it, assuming forgiveness is necessary.
```

I know the meaning is very close, but I would like to hear opinions as to the nuances, the usage in American English everyday speech, especially in terms of age, formality, and level of education.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks very like an artificial example and either way, it hardly belongs here.

However, in that example "called for" is broadly equivalent to "justified" while "necessary" roughly means "vital."

Does that make sense?

Comment: That's a useful distinction. I don't understand what you mean by artificial though.

Comment: When exactly is forgiveness something that is "called for" or "required"? I feel like this example doesn't really make sense for this reason. If I say, "That is something I can understand, and even forgive.", the very fact that I am saying it is something I could forgive says that I consider it a thing which "needs" forgiven. That being said, I think what you're ACTUALLY looking for in the examples here is "warranted". "That I can understand and even forgive, if it is something which warrants forgiveness."

Comment: Oh, and to actually answer your question, there is not a lot of difference between "called for" and "necessary" how you have used them. Here are some other examples. "The recipe calls for 3 eggs." would be used and NOT "The recipe says that 3 eggs are necessary." "When learning a language, it is often necessary to immerse oneself in the language." would be used and NOT "When learning a language, it is often called for to immerse oneself in the language." Who is calling for it?

Comment: @RonKyle  I think that it means that what appears to need forgiveness may actually just need an explanation, such as not getting the message.

Comment: @Mary - Yeah, that's what I was thinking when I  suggested the word they wanted was "warranted"..

Comment: warranted doesn't sound to me as a term someone would use in everyday speech. My example was probably incomplete, so I will amend the post to make it clearer.

Comment: warranted doesn't sound to me as a term someone would use in everyday speech. My example was probably incomplete, so I will amend the post to make it clearer. As for the the meaning of the phrase, the speaker is saying that he/she can forgive the deed in question, but it is debatable if forgivenes is required, morally or otherwise.

Comment: @ black-clover, Opinions on nuance or usage by age, formality, education or what belong first to your dictionaries and search engines, then somewhere like English Language Learners. Could it matter why that looked artificial? (It’s because even if a native used those phrases, none would compare them that way.) FYI, “warranted” is used every day by the educated, eloquent, erudite, etc. That it doesn’t crop up in common-or-garden speech reflects only the teaching of Jo Public. Your speaker is saying nothing about morality. Debate whether forgiveness was required should be your point… –